# Easiest way to find top holders of token from past blocks

Tags: bsc, bscscan

I forked the binance smart chain mainnet at block X. I want to interact with other contracts. The issue is I need to find an address (whale) that has a large amount of particular BEP-20 token (SAT WBNB)

What is the easiest way to find top holders at block X?

Answer (score 0):

Use Bitquery's APIs. Here's the graphQL query to get wallets with most SAT tokens.

https://ide.bitquery.io/Top-10-SAT-Wallets-on-BSC